# New fonts in Mathematica 10.4

Tags: version-10, fonts

According to this [page](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html), Mathematica v10.4

> Added support for 24 new font families for additional customization of web and print work.

My question is simple: Where can I find the new font families? By the way, I don't have this version of Mathematica installed

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This question is discussed in the following recent Wolfram Community thread: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/817955

Comment: possibly just adding back support for fonts they had previously dropped. For example I notice "Webdings" in there. Supported previously then dropped now back.

Comment: But do they support any Klingon font???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fonts in version 10.3.1

```
v1031 = {"Al Bayan", "Al Nile", "Al Tarikh", "American Typewriter", 
   "Andale Mono", "Apple Braille", "Apple Chancery", 
   "Apple Color Emoji", "AppleGothic", "AppleMyungjo", 
   "Apple SD Gothic Neo", "Apple Symbols", "Arial", "Arial Black", 
   "Arial Hebrew", "Arial Hebrew Scholar", "Arial Narrow", 
   "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Arial Unicode MS", "Athelas", "Avenir", 
   "Avenir Next", "Avenir Next Condensed", "Ayuthaya", "Baghdad", 
   "Bangla MN", "Bangla Sangam MN", "Baoli SC", "Baskerville", 
   "Beirut", "Big Caslon", "Bodoni 72", "Bodoni 72 Oldstyle", 
   "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps", "Bodoni Ornaments", "Bradley Hand", 
   "Brush Script MT", "Chalkboard", "Chalkboard SE", "Chalkduster", 
   "Charter", "Cochin", "Comic Sans MS", "Copperplate", 
   "Corsiva Hebrew", "Courier", "Courier New", "Damascus", 
   "DecoType Naskh", "Devanagari MT", "Devanagari Sangam MN", "Didot",
    "DIN Alternate", "DIN Condensed", "Diwan Kufi", "Diwan Thuluth", 
   "Euphemia UCAS", "Farah", "Farisi", "Futura", "GB18030 Bitmap", 
   "Geeza Pro", "Geneva", "Georgia", "Gill Sans", "Gujarati MT", 
   "Gujarati Sangam MN", "GungSeo", "Gurmukhi MN", "Gurmukhi MT", 
   "Gurmukhi Sangam MN", "Hannotate SC", "Hannotate TC", 
   "HanziPen SC", "HanziPen TC", "HeadLineA", "Heiti SC", "Heiti TC", 
   "Helvetica", "Helvetica Neue", "Herculanum", 
   "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", 
   "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Std", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic StdN", 
   "Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro", "Hiragino Maru Gothic ProN", 
   "Hiragino Mincho Pro", "Hiragino Mincho ProN", "Hiragino Sans", 
   "Hiragino Sans GB", "Hoefler Text", "Impact", "InaiMathi", 
   "Iowan Old Style", "ITF Devanagari", "ITF Devanagari Marathi", 
   "Kailasa", "Kaiti SC", "Kaiti TC", "Kannada MN", 
   "Kannada Sangam MN", "Kefa", "Khmer MN", "Khmer Sangam MN", "Klee",
    "Kohinoor Bangla", "Kohinoor Devanagari", "Kohinoor Telugu", 
   "Kokonor", "Krungthep", "KufiStandardGK", "Lantinghei SC", 
   "Lantinghei TC", "Lao MN", "Lao Sangam MN", "Libian SC", 
   "LiHei Pro", "LiSong Pro", "Lucida Grande", "Luminari", 
   "Malayalam MN", "Malayalam Sangam MN", "Marion", "Marker Felt", 
   "Menlo", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "Mishafi", "Mishafi Gold", 
   "Monaco", "Mshtakan", "Muna", "Myanmar MN", "Myanmar Sangam MN", 
   "Nadeem", "Nanum Brush Script", "Nanum Gothic", "Nanum Myeongjo", 
   "Nanum Pen Script", "New Peninim MT", "Noteworthy", "Optima", 
   "Oriya MN", "Oriya Sangam MN", "Osaka", "Palatino", "Papyrus", 
   "PCMyungjo", "Phosphate", "PilGi", "PingFang HK", "PingFang SC", 
   "PingFang TC", "Plantagenet Cherokee", "PT Mono", "PT Sans", 
   "PT Sans Caption", "PT Sans Narrow", "PT Serif", 
   "PT Serif Caption", "Raanana", "Sana", "Sathu", "Savoye LET", 
   "Seravek", "Shree Devanagari 714", "SignPainter", "Silom", 
   "Sinhala MN", "Sinhala Sangam MN", "Skia", "Snell Roundhand", 
   "Songti SC", "Songti TC", "Source Sans Pro", "STFangsong", 
   "STHeiti", "STIXGeneral", "STIXIntegralsD", "STIXIntegralsSm", 
   "STIXIntegralsUp", "STIXIntegralsUpD", "STIXIntegralsUpSm", 
   "STIXNonUnicode", "STIXSizeFiveSym", "STIXSizeFourSym", 
   "STIXSizeOneSym", "STIXSizeThreeSym", "STIXSizeTwoSym", 
   "STIXVariants", "STKaiti", "STSong", "Sukhumvit Set", 
   "Superclarendon", "Symbol", "Tahoma", "Tamil MN", 
   "Tamil Sangam MN", "Telugu MN", "Telugu Sangam MN", "Thonburi", 
   "Times", "Times New Roman", "Trattatello", "Trebuchet MS", 
   "Tsukushi A Round Gothic", "Tsukushi B Round Gothic", "Verdana", 
   "Waseem", "Wawati SC", "Wawati TC", "Webdings", "Weibei SC", 
   "Weibei TC", "Wingdings", "Wingdings 2", "Wingdings 3", 
   "Xingkai SC", "Yuanti SC", "Yuanti TC", "YuGothic", "YuMincho", 
   "YuMincho +36p Kana", "Yuppy SC", "Yuppy TC", "Zapf Dingbats", 
   "Zapfino"};
```

Fonts in version 10.4.0

```
v1040 = $FontFamilies;
```

New fonts in version 10.4.0

```
Complement[v1040, v1031]

(*  {"Alegreya SC", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Clear Sans", "Clear Sans \
Light", "Clear Sans Medium", "Clear Sans Thin", "Cousine", "Droid \
Serif", "EB Garamond", "EB Garamond 12 All SC", "EB Garamond SC", \
"Economica", "Felipa", "Gentium Basic", "Inconsolata", "Kalam", \
"Lato", "League Gothic", "Oswald", "Playfair Display", "Roboto", \
"Roboto Condensed", "Roboto Slab", "Shadows Into Light Two", "Source \
Code Pro", "Source Serif Pro", "Titillium Web", "Yanone Kaffeesatz"}  *)

Length[%]

(*  28  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what is your OS?

Comment: @David - Mac OS X 10.11.3

Answer (score 1):

```
Style[#, FontFamily -> #] & /@ $FontFamilies
```

Comment: Will this give the **new** families or all families?